# How to create dmp file of Oracle database?

Tags: database, import, oracle10g, export

I have database which resides in my Oracle 10g. I need to carry it to another PC. What should I do to import and export it to another PC?

Answer (score 3):

As you are on 10g you should use the DataPump utility.  [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/part_dp.htm#i436481)

This supplanted [the Import and Export utilities](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#i1023560) which were available in older versions of the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of articles that describe the way to do that.

[Oracle export and import](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import+)

[The ORACLE Import/Export Utilities](http://www-it.desy.de/systems/services/databases/oracle/impexp/impexp.html.en)